# How to pass variable serialize through ajax to codeigniter controller?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

My view:

```
  $('#frm_ingreso').submit(function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    url: `${RUTA}retaso-ingreso/guardar`,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      "data": $('#frm_ingreso').serialize()
    },
  })
  .done((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  });
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

My Controller:

I show all post with `print_r($_POST)` and it´s shown, but when I want to pass variable each data:

```
public function guardar(){  
  print_r($_POST);  
  /*
     Array
     (
      [data] => 
       cboMaterial=2&cboTipo=3&cboColor=2
     )
  */
  $material = $this->input->post("cboMaterial"); // error it's show nothing
  echo $material; // its show nothing
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to set a variable on a view or have the POST response return something on the client side. I agree with Drwness we need to see the controller code. Is `input` an object? `post` is nothing as it stands. You'd being looking for `$name = $_POST["txtName"];` if `txtName` was the name of the input on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this:

`data: $('#frm_ingreso').serialize()`

Usage:

```
$('#frm_ingreso').submit(function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    url: `${RUTA}retaso-ingreso/guardar`,
    type: 'POST',
    data: $('#frm_ingreso').serialize(),
  })
  .done((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  });
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

and `$material = $this->input->post("cboMaterial");` should work